# Android - App crashing due to memory error

Tags: android, memory, gridview, crash

I have an app that is not graphic intensive (as such). It has 2 Fragments, both with 2 GridViews inside. This is what I call Level-1 Activities because they are visible immediately when the app is opened.

Now the second GridView located inside Fragment #2 has 3 items, one of these Items opens a New Activity with a GridView inside it. This is what I call Level-2 Activities as they must be accessed by the user.

This second level GridView has 8 Image items. The Items are all identical size and shape, but the Images used for them are not, so they are scaled/resized etc. The Images are:

Image 1 - 465x232, 38kb

Image 2 - 512x251, 41kb

Image 3 - 900x379, 68kb

Image 4 - 630x258, 35kb

Image 5 - 700x346, 44kb

Image 6 - 615x409, 24kb

Image 7 - 800x383, 64kb

Image 8 - 400x169, 26kb

**GridView XML**

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/essentials_gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

**GridView Item Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="125dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+list/grid_item_image_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />"

    <TextView
        android:id="@+list/grid_item_image_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#50000000"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Error I get is:

```
08-10 10:09:42.060: E/dalvikvm-heap(18982): Out of memory on a 9023376-byte allocation.
```

This happens when I'm moving back and forth between the Level 1 and Level 2 activities. After couple of times, it crashes with that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have a memory leak, I suggest you to watch this session:

[Google I/O 2011: Memory management for Android Apps](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk)

In my own experience, I recommend you to implement ViewHolder pattern inside your Gridview's adapters.

Comment: Ill give that a go :) and post here again

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is related to image handling. You could try to use sampled version of the original if they are big. You could also cache the image that will be memory efficient. When you are navigating between the activities the images are loading again and again and consuming the memory.

The following link could be useful here. If you post your sample java code where you are loading image then it will be possible to pin point your issue.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Comment: I have removed the images completely, using a simple textview instead.